# Free automation tool for windows and linux OS

Tags: linux, windows, automation, open-source

For my projects I need an open source tool for automation testing. My programs are running under Windows and Linux OS. I need something like Selenium for web applications, only that your recommended tool should be for windows applications.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about Desktop/Standalone application? I mean your program is not a web app, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite a lot like

- Grinder
- Pylot
- Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT)
- fwptt (Fast web Performance test tool)
- Apache JMeter
- Web Polygraph
- OpenSTA

Most of them are written by java or python and you can use in Windows or Linux. There is difference in focus, try :)